# Transitioning a project from Cocos2d v1.x to v2.x and then to ARC

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, refactoring, automatic-ref-counting

I might sound lazy but I am slightly confused on how to proceed on this subject. I have followed [this guide](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/) which is very well done.

My goal is to convert the Cocos2d v1.x game project to Cocos2d v2.x and then refactor the project code to ARC.

To get started I created an empty HelloWorld Cocos2d v2.x project and created the v2.x static library (as from Steffen's guide). I then rafactored the code to ARC and the HelloWorld worked smoothly.

The issue is when I try to add to the same project the classes I had already written that don't complain to ARC (assuming that there will be not many Cocos2d v2.x vs v1.x problems - e.g. use of deprecated methods and classes like TouchJSON - my project doesn't at least as far I can see). So, I added a couple of Game classes that don't depend from the rest of the game (to reduce the number of potential Cocos2d v2. Vs v1 issues) to the project to see if the ARC covnersion worked for those as a proof of concept. After adding them I choosed: EDIT->Refactor option from XCode.

But now the compiler gives me some ARC warning messages like "ARC forbids explicit message send of autorelease" in the following method:

```
return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Or similar problems with the dealloc method already written.

I was assuming that EDIT->Refactor would have changed the added code but it appears to work only once. Any hint on this? **should I add all my code to the new project template before refactoring the code?**

EDIT:To verify whether it was an XCode bug I created an empty iOS project with no Cocos2d libraries and then converted it to ARC. Then created a new empty sublcass of NSObject and added a dealloc method and run the conversion again, it did work! So I might have not followed correctly some of the steps to create and link to the static library..

In addition to this there are some other small issues (not XCode related, but Cocos2d v2.x related), like the fact that the **CDXPropertyModifierAction** is not automatically included to the CocosDenshion folder and I had to add it to the project after creating the static library (when I noticed the issue).. but I guess this is more template creation related.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: apparently I am getting close to the solution. I basically re-created a Cocos2d 2.x test project,moved Cocos2d to a static library, converted the HelloWorld class,build and run successfully, and now added some new test classes. Those were not being converted by the XCode converter to ARC code, and so I deselected the main.m and the previously converted classes from the menu showing to which classes the conversion was going to be applied. I'll post a detailed solution tomorrow if the solution will apply to the entire game project (but pls if you have other answers pls do post :)). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, yeah, I can confirm that the solution in the comment did work. As usual with some IT things is was just about playing around a bit with the various options and see if it works changing the prospective (its not a bug but is me being stupid or lazy).

What worked for me was to use the EDIT->Refactor from the XCode menu and de-select the files created in the first instance by the Cocos2d 2.x template that I had converted after creating the static library (e.g. main.m and AppDelegate.m) (ask if this is unclear).
This converted smoothly all my newly converted Cocos2d 2.x classes into ARC complaint classes and yeah, I have my project fully supporting both Cocos2d 2.x and ARC :).

Please find below the screenshot of the files I deselected to get it working:
[image]